# How to insert and center text in Google Docs with script

Tags: google-apps-script, centering

I want to make a script that inserts text like this at the end of my document:

```
                            February 18, 2015
                                  Title
   Entry
```

Where the first two lines are centered and the last line is indented with a tab.

This is what I have so far:

```
  function addJournalTemplate(){
  var currDate = new Date();
  var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
  var dateString = months[currDate.getMonth()] + ' ' + (currDate.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + currDate.getDate() : currDate.getDate()) + ', ' + currDate.getYear(); 
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var dateText = doc.getBody().editAsText().appendText(dateString);

  var title = doc.getBody().insertParagraph(1, 'Title');
  title.setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
}
```

And that code doesn't work at all. I am lost and have been searching developers.google.com for about an hour now.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i modified your script.

your prob :

```
var dateText = doc.getBody().editAsText().appendText(dateString);
```

You can't center with this method, it's better to use  the method ( insertParagraph() )

```
function addJournalTemplate(){
  var currDate = new Date();
  var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
  var dateString = months[currDate.getMonth()] + ' ' + (currDate.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + currDate.getDate() : currDate.getDate()) + ', ' + currDate.getYear(); 

  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('myid');
  var dateText = doc.getBody().insertParagraph(1,dateString);
  dateText.setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

  var title = doc.getBody().insertParagraph(2, 'Title');
  title.setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
  return doc;
}
```

Comment: That totally centers them! Nice change! Man, I was so close. 

That last issue is that the number in the insertParagraph, which is the index where the paragraph gets inserted, needs to be the end of the document. How to I dynamically get the index of the end of the document?

Comment: You can add a footer in your document.
Class : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/footer-section

Implementation ( class : Document -> addFooter method )

Comment: @casey intead of insertParagraph(index, string) use the method .appendParagraph(text) which puts the paragraph at the end of the document