# How do you center text horizontally inside cells when inputting a template in docs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Here's what I have:

```
function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('New Table')
  .addItem('Add Table', 'addTable')
  .addToUi();
}

function addTable() {
  
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  
 
 // body.insertHorizontalRule(1);
//  var center = body.insertParagraph(1, ' ');
// center.setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);



  var cells = [
  ['', 'Lunch','Dinner'],
  ['SALES', ' ',''],
  ['MEALS', ' ',''],
  ['IDEAL STAFFING LEVELS'],
  ['Senior','',''],
  ['Junior','',''],
  ['Host','',''],
  ['Kitchen','',''],
  ['Dish','',''],
  ['Service','',''],
  ['Expo','',''],
  ['Skip','',''],
  ['Super','',''],
  [' '],
  ['Weather','',''],
  ['Events','',''],
  ['Other','',''],

['Day Manager:',''],
['Log:',''],
['Night Manager',''],
['Log',''],
];


  var table1 = body.insertTable(2,cells);
  

  table1.setColumnWidth(0, 125);
  table1.setColumnWidth(1, 100);
  table1.setColumnWidth(2, 100);
 
    var style = {};
    
  // style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] =
  // DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER;

  //style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 7;
  //style.table1.setVerticalAlignment(DocumentApp.VerticalAlignment.CENTER)
  //style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER;
  table1.setAttributes(style);


//     var alignment = {};
//     alignment[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] =
//   DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER;
//  //alignment.setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

//      table1.setAttributes(alignment);



var tableHeader = table1.getRow(0);

  var headerStyle = {};  
//headerStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = '#C0C0C0';  
headerStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true; 
  
  tableHeader.setAttributes(headerStyle);


  var tableBold1 = table1.getRow(1);

  var boldStyle = {};    
boldStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true; 
  
  tableBold1.setAttributes(boldStyle);
  

  var tableBold2 = table1.getRow(2);

  var boldStyle = {};    
boldStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true; 
  
  tableBold2.setAttributes(boldStyle);


  var tableBold3 = table1.getRow(3);

  var boldStyle = {};    
boldStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true; 
  
  tableBold3.setAttributes(boldStyle);

 

}
```

Tried a variety of ways I have come across as seen in my notes but I am new to this and only starting to understand the smallest bits. I've read something about maybe needing to use insertParagraph here: [How to insert and center text in Google Docs with script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599838/how-to-insert-and-center-text-in-google-docs-with-script/28604555) but am unable to figure out the correct format for that to work in this circumstance.

I would also like to be able to return the font size to normal after the table. What is the proper function for that?

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance
thisisnotadupp

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide the sample output you expect as an image?

Comment: Take a look at setAttributes: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-cell#setAttributes(Object)

Comment: @metaman can you get this to work? I've tested this directly with `style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER` but after setting the attributes to the table cell the text is still not horizontally aligned. Also looping through the tablecell elements and logging the attributes after the fact shows that the style was never applied. Can you confirm if you can get this to work? Otherwise I think it might be a bug.

Comment: Logging the style returns `{BACKGROUND_COLOR=, PADDING_RIGHT=5.0, LINK_URL=null, UNDERLINE=null, PADDING_BOTTOM=5.0, FONT_FAMILY=null, BOLD=null, STRIKETHROUGH=null, VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT=Top, FONT_SIZE=7.0, ITALIC=null, FOREGROUND_COLOR=null, WIDTH=null, PADDING_LEFT=5.0, PADDING_TOP=5.0}` for reference. No horizontal alignment property in sight.

Comment: I'll try setting up an example and take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

#### This appears to be a bug!

I have taken the liberty of reporting this on Google's Issue Tracker for you, detailing the behaviour:

- [Horizontal and Vertical alignment not being respected programmatically in table cells in Google Docs](https://issuetracker.google.com/189089644)

You can hit the ☆ next to the issue number in the top left on the page which lets Google know more people are encountering this and so it is more likely to be seen to faster.